# Azure Mobile Services - complex processing

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I am fairly new to Azure and mobile services, and all the examples and tutorials I can find for the table and API scripts are fairly simplistic.

If I have some processes that are fairly complex and rely on pulling information from many different tables and processing contingent on that data, should I be doing that somewhere other than the API scripts? I am new to node.js as well so maybe that's the problem but I was wondering if there is a more appropriate place for business logic, such as some bridge I need to add to my stack?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of examples of how to use MSSql object which is used to query tables and Node in general available.  A healthy search will reveal just about anything you need.  Since you said you are new to Node.js consider using the .NET backend instead.  It is based on Entity Framework and there are lots of Entity framework examples out there for you too.  Finally, there are some really good examples of complex logic being used in the back ends in the sample code available:  http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/develop/mobile/ios-samples/ (pick your client OS) and here: http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/topics/mobile/ and here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/azuremobile/

Let us know if you have specific questions!

Comment: Thanks, I have been using the mssql a bit and it's useful. I wanted to go with Node first just to learn something new and see if I could keep it javascript end to end. I'm building a cross platform app with ionic/angularjs/phonegap(cordova)/azure mobile, so I was avoiding the specific OS instructions. 
Thanks for the other links too, I'll have to check them out.